# synthetic division algorithm to deflate conjugate pairs

Tags: c, algorithm, numerical-methods

I am implementing a synthetic division algorithm in C as follows:

```
int deflate( double r, double im, double* poly, int n ) {
    int retval;
    int i;
    if( im == 0 ) {
            if( n < 1 ) {
                    retval = 1;
            } else {
                    double* out = ( double* )malloc( ( n )*sizeof( double ) );
                    out[ n - 1 ] = poly[ n ];
                    for( i = n - 2; i >= 0; i-- ) {
                            out[ i ] = out[ i + 1 ]*r + poly[ i + 1 ];
                    }

                    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
                            poly[ i ] = out[ i ];
                    }
                    poly[ n ] = 0;
                    free( out );
                    retval = 0;
            }
    } else {
            if( n < 2 ) {
                    retval = 1;
            } else {
                    /*code to handle complex numbers here*/
                    retval = 0;
            }
    }
    return retval;
}
```

I am trying to think of an efficient way to implement this for a non-zero imaginary component. Specifically, I would like to deflate both complex conjugate roots in one pass, without having to work with a complex coefficient polynomial. Can anyone think of a way to do this?

Comment: This may be a bit math-y for stackoverflow. The audience at http://cs.stackexchange.com might be more suited to help you with this; they're pretty good at programming math problems, so code doesn't scare them off.

Comment: @G.Bach ah ok. I wasn't sure if it belonged here, cs, or math :)

Comment: I'm not, either :) But I'd go for CS, I think most programmers forget whatever formal math courses they had soon after graduation.

Comment: If on C99 or more you could use a VLA (`double out[n]`) to leave allocation/deallocation to the compiler. If this speeds things up you have to benchmark.

Comment: @alk I would still need to find a way to deflate the conjugate pairs in one pass, even if the compiler handled the allocation.

Comment: @ZettaSuro: Just let deflate calls itself if a root was found for the first value of the pair of conjugates.

Comment: @ZettaSuro: Your snippet seems to be missing the actual test whether the value for `r` is a root to `poly` or not.

Comment: @alk "Just let deflate calls itself if a root was found for the first value of the pair of conjugates." I'm not sure what you mean, are you talking about doing a recursive call? If so, that still doesn't solve the problem of having to work with a complex polynomial after deflating for first complex root, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @alk Nothing, I just chose not to use it. Are you talking about using a struct? Wouldn't that be the same functionality?

Comment: @ZettaSuro: Since C99 complex numbers are implicitly supported: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex.h#complex.h and for GCC: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Complex.html

Comment: @alk Ah, I see. Fortunately I've managed to come up with a solution. Thank you for your assistance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure out a way to do this. The solution is a simple matter of understanding that deflating a conjugate pair is just deflating two roots at once, both of which form a second polynomial, which is the divisor of the operation:

```
double div1 = -2*r;
double div0 = r*r + im*im;
```

Now use these two values to do synthetic division in the same way as you would if you were doing long division between a polynomial and a quadratic whose leading coefficient is 1 (which is essentially what synthetic division is in the case of a real root, except the divisor is linear whether than quadratic):

```
int i;
out[ n - 2 ] = poly[ n ];
out[ n - 3 ] = -out[ n - 2 ]*div1 + poly[ n - 1 ];
for( i = n - 4; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    out[ i ] = -out[ i + 2 ]*div0 + -out[ i + 1 ]*div1 + poly[ i + 2 ];
}
for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    poly[ i ] = out[ i ];
}
poly[ n - 1 ] = 0.0;
poly[ n ] = 0.0;
free( out );
retval = 0;
```

This entirely bypasses the need to form a complex coefficient polynomial, and deflates both complex roots in a single pass.